# How to make Laravel login Security like Facebook using latitude or longitude?

Tags: laravel

I am making project in laravel.When user login his dashboard from one city but In 5 minutes when another non-user tried to access his dashboard from another city then message should be thrown to user Because it is impossible to travel from one city to another city in just 5 minutes.So I have column for latitude and longitude where i can get data from below API link.Can you give me more suggestion how should i do it?Do i need to make other column also to avoid this problem ?

This is my user database where i have store last_login_at and last_login_IP

```
id | name | email | phone | email_verified_at | password | last_login_at | last_login_ip |longitude |latitude |created_at |
```

I my trying to use this http://ip-api.com/php/24.48.0.1 API that detect the user location from IP. This is data i get from API

```
{
  "query": "24.48.0.1",
  "status": "success",
  "country": "Canada",
  "countryCode": "CA",
  "region": "QC",
  "regionName": "Quebec",
  "city": "Montreal",
  "zip": "H1S",
  "lat": 45.5808,
  "lon": -73.5825,
  "timezone": "America/Toronto",
  "isp": "Le Groupe Videotron Ltee",
  "org": "Videotron Ltee",
  "as": "AS5769 Videotron Telecom Ltee"
}
```

This is my LoginController.php

```
function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        $client = new  \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $url = "http://ip-api.com/php/24.48.0.1";
        $response = $client->request("GET", $url);
        $response=(array) json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
        
        $user->update([
             'last_login_at' => Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString(),
             'last_login_ip' => $request->getClientIp(),
             'longitude' => $response['lat'],
             'latitude' => $response['lon'],
        ]);
       
    }
```

Comment: Does Facebook really do what you are trying to do?

Comment: I think yes.1 month ago 1 notifcation pop up in my mobile day .Are you really trying to attempt this login something.it show from another city and ip address

Comment: Facebook just check for different location not time.

Comment: So what would be your suggestion to check city and ip address  ?

Comment: But what if a different person tries to access the dashboard while being in the same city? Would that be allowed? Of course not. This is not how things work. Normally login systems tend to look for specific devices or device settings even. Look into "fingerprinting". Also, seeing a cookie after a successful login might be really helpful already....